# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, react-native

i'm on Android Studio with an React Native project. Works fine on Xcode but A/S side i get a bunch of errors i'm not familiar with:-

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase.
```

Assume i need to run the equivalent of an npm install somewhere? Or add in React Native Firebase somewhere? or remove it?

Bizarrely React Native Firebase is *NOT* in my pkg json dependencies at all. I just use the web api for that - it only exists in Android Studio.

Help?

Comment: hi! Have you solved this issue? I see this errors right now after moving a project from Windows to Linux.

Comment: @Inoy i sort of abandoned React Native projects exactly because of issues like this. As a React Web Developer i felt drawn to RN for obv reasons. It would allow me to build apps in JS exploting *some* of the native benefits for a phone app (offline functionality, slick performance, storage etc) But i found the persistent Xcode v Android Studio errors incredibly frustrating.
Not to say u should abandon it too. If ure skilled in Java, Swift & React it's beautiful. For prototypes its fun & quick. But for core JS devs its *days* spent trying to debug unhelpful Android Studio errors.

Comment: now I know what the issue was in my case - the URL for a library was changed. That's why it was working OK on my main PC (cached lib), but I couldn't build a project on another PC - IDE is Unable to resolve dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've answered your own question. You need to `npm install` it, and then either `react-native link` it or manually add it to your settings.gradle, app/build.gradle, and MainApplication class.
Have a look at the [official setup guide](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup).

Comment: Tried and no difference. Not sure why it's looking for `Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-firebase: ` though? I'm not using React Native Firebase, i'm just using the web api for Firebase. There is no RNF in my pkg json? Any ideas?

Comment: what if i want to remove RNF from my android project?

Comment: I think you previously installed RNFirebase and then switched to Firebase Web. First, unlink RNFirebase and go for Firebase Web.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found out the cause is a version mismatch. I had my firebase version upgraded to a high level and my react-native version was too low for the package to work.

upgrading react-native itself solved the issue.